# when i select different item than tab in action bar overline on last tab dissapear android

Tags: android, xml

i have an issuea with my actionbar. I have actionbar which have 3 tabs and 1 icon "fauvorite". To each tabs i add selector which gave me overline on selected tab, but when i click on the fauvorite icon the last selected tab don't have overline. I know it is an issue with focusableInTouchMode but i want to icon "fauvorite" could be clicked too.

Now i have something like this:

[tabIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecTMG.jpg)

My selector for each tab:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="true">

    <layer-list>
      <item android:bottom="-6dp" android:left="-6dp" android:right="-6dp">
        <shape>
          <solid android:color="#30cfcfe1"/>
          <stroke android:color="#800000" android:width="6dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>

    </layer-list> 
  </item>

  <item android:state_focused="true">

    <layer-list>
      <item android:bottom="-6dp" android:left="-6dp" android:right="-6dp">
        <shape>
          <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
          <stroke android:color="#800000" android:width="6dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>

  </item>

  <item>
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Do you know how to make a situation in which when i clicked on "fauvorite" icon the last selected tab will contains overline ?